# AutoMapper same profile class in seperated projects IoC in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, automapper

In our solution we have multiple projects:

```
Project.Core

Project.Web

Project.Test

Project.Web.UI
```

In my Core project I have my DTO classes and my Entity classes.

In my Web project I have my ViewModels.

For mapping I am using `AutoMapper` and I need to set up profiles in both my Core and Web project.

For instance:

I have in my Core project a `UserDto` and `User` class. I create a mapping profile called `UserProfile` which takes care of this mapping.

```
/// <summary>
/// Mapping profile for users
/// </summary>
internal class UserProfile : Profile
{
    public UserProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<User, UserDto>()
            .ForMember(
                dto => dto.Id,
                expression => expression.Condition(src => src.HasIdentity)
            ).ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

Then in my Web project I do the same:

```
/// <summary>
/// Mapping profile for users
/// </summary>
internal class UserProfile : Profile
{
    public UserProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<User, UserModel>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<User, UserDetailModel>().ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

As you can see I have 2 `UserProfile` classes in seperated projects.

For IoC I am using Autofac:

```
// Register Automapper

builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.Load("Project.Core")).As<Profile>();

builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.Load("Project.Web")).As<Profile>();
        builder.Register(context => new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            foreach (var profile in context.Resolve<IEnumerable<Profile>>())
            {
                cfg.AddProfile(profile);
            }
        })).AsSelf().SingleInstance();
        builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<MapperConfiguration>().CreateMapper(c.Resolve))
            .As<AutoMapper.IMapper>()
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Is it bad to have a duplicate name profile AutoMapper class but seperated in different projects and should I rename one of the classes?

Comment: Of course, you can still discern the class by their namespace. Sooner or later you (or more likely another developer) will mix up the classes. Names that seem clear now won't seem clear some months later. So IMO using a different name would be preferable. Maybe you can use `UserDtoProfile` and `UserModelProfile` as names.

Comment: @Markus you're correct, I think it will indeed be the best for everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, you can still discern the class by their namespace. But sooner or later you (or more likely another developer) will mix up the classes. Names that seem clear now won't seem clear some months later.

IMO using a different name would be preferable. Maybe you can use `UserDtoProfile` and `UserModelProfile` as names.